# Unable to store entire CLOB data in to CLOB defined column in DB2

Tags: db2, clob

I am unable to upload the entire clob data using db2 load. Only the data till a certain length is put into the column(CLOB) of the  table.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details. Show the exact command that is failing , and all of its output and messages. Write your Db2-server version and platform details.   Show the encoding of the database or target-table.   If you give no details in your question, it will get closed fast.

Comment: There is a 32K limitation for large data objects inlined into a base file. If you have larger LOB, then place it to a distinct file, reference this file name in a base file instead of actual data, use the `LOBS FROM directory_with_lob_files` clause of the `LOAD` command. That is your record should look like `"val1",123,...,"file1.txt",...`, where `file1.txt` is a file with your CLOB contents in the `directory_with_lob_files` directory.